# capture a vertical movement of the phone as a horizontal (android)

Tags: android

I try to create an android app which captures a vertical movement of the cellphone as a horizontal movement. I am not sure if swapping y axis with x axis of the device is enough or should I also change a gravity field coordinates? Thank you in advance.